# How can I get a welcome-file-list?

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml

On Tomcat 4.x it's working

```
String redirectURL = request.getContextPath() + "/"
        + ((String[]) pageContext.findAttribute(
                "org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES"))[0];
```

, but on Tomcat 7.0.x it doesn't work. And gave me a NullPointerException.

How I can get a welcome files on a new Tomcat 7.0.x ?

Comment: Do not knwo what you are trying to achieve, but why not just let Tomcat do its stuff and redirect to request.getContextPath() + "/".  This should then try to go to the first welcome file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get them with ServletContext.getAttribute("org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES") nowadays.